# If everything is an "object" in javascript isn't "creating objects" redundant?

Tags: javascript

I've heard that "everything in javascript is an object" according to many tutorials and people across the internet.  However, I'm also well aware of several methods to "create objects", such as a constructor, a factory or an object literal.

What I don't understand is...if "everything is an object" why should I have to "create one"?  Isn't the creation of a variable the creation of "an object"?  Isn't the creation of a function the creation of an object?

What are we really creating when we say we are "creating objects"?

Comment: The phrase  "everything is an object" refers to **values** in JavaScript. Everything but values of primitive data types are objects. You also have to distinguish between syntax and runtime semantics. Objects only exist at runtime. An "object literal" is a syntax construct that tells the engine to create a specific object and how it should look like.

Comment: Everything is awesome, Everything is cool when you're part of an object...

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up.  I don't see why this question is being downvoted.  It is quite ambiguous to a newbie to read "everything is an object in javascript" and then two seconds later everyone is saying "but not everything is an object".  Things like this are important for newbies to know about.  Saying "all 'values' but primitives are objects" !== "everything is an object", this needed to be clarified since many tutorials, books and websites keep pushing this idea.

Answer (score 4):

> What I don't understand is...if "everything is an object" why should I have to "create one"?Isn't the creation of a variable the creation of "an object"?

No... Variables are kind of like names for things. It's like saying "If we want a baby, we already know we'll call it Jamie, why should we need sex?"

Variables just point at objects, but are not objects themselves. Comments are not objects either. Nor is the `for` keyword, nor curly braces, nor the assignment operator `=`. In fact, most things in JavaScript are, really, not objects.

However, everything that you can assign to your variable, is. Except integers. And other numbers. And truth values. And some other stuff we call "primitive types". However they kind of behave like objects (as in, you can call methods on them). So... not nearly everything.

So... when you say `var a = {}`, what you are doing is really...

- creating an empty object, `{}`
- declaring a variable `a`
- telling the variable `a` that it should point to that empty object.

When you say `var b = a`, you say "I want to have a variable `b`, and I want it to point at the same thing `a` already is. It's like saying "We have John, that's this guy here. Let's also call him 'Prettyboy'." From then on, you have two names for the same object. But giving John another name is not making another human.

Comment: The example is bad since you are using a number literal which results in a primitive value. But overall I like your explanation.

Comment: @FelixKling: Yeah, I just edited in a clarification. Actually, scrap that, I'll just put in an object literal.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [not everything is an object in JavaScript](http://blog.brew.com.hk/not-everything-in-javascript-is-an-object/). There are six primitive types and an object type. Every piece of data must fall within one of these types.

Second of all, and 'object' is a type, when you 'create an object', you are creating a modified ***copy*** of that type. This is *similar* to creating an instance of a class if you come from a more classical object-oriented programming (OOP) language.

Compare that to a real-world example - there are things called 'Cars', so why do we need to create more cars?